# Using Repository Pattern for two tables without relation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository

How can I use the Repository Pattern in C# to get data from two tables without the relationship setup between them in the database?  For example, I have a table for students and a table for details:

```
public class Student{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int GenderId{get;set;}
}

public class DetailsLookup{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

I set data for `GenderId` from `DetailsLookup.Id` but it doesn't create a relationship between them in the database.

I'm using the Repository Pattern in my code and Unit of work.  I have an idea to return `StudentViewModel`.

```
public class StudentViewModel{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int GenderId{get;set;}
    public int GenderName{get;set;}
}
```

[But based on what I read here](https://programmingwithmosh.com/net/common-mistakes-with-the-repository-pattern/), we can't return view models/DTOs from Repositories.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: and talking of not returning viewmodels from repository, that's not true. you can return any class you want. but as a best practice, when you have multiple operations to perform based on a single query, you should return database object and use it as per the need. that way you can make your code reusable and easy to maintain. for your custom requirement, you need to return a custom class so you can combine the results from multiple tables.

Comment: So, if I need return join query , I can use ViewModel in repo? I created repos for All domains but if I want return data from multi domain , I faced issue , Is good return two repo and join them in services or create viewmodel in repor

Comment: yes, you can return viewmodel from repo. That is not a restriction. It is just a best practice to return database objects directly when possible, so you can reuse them. For this scenario, it is best to join queries and return viewmodel as suggested in the answer.

Comment: did I answer the question? If yes, you may want to mark it as an answer so others can be benefited from it.

Comment: yes , Done :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about returning a viewmodel from repo, fetch records separately and merge them in service layer.

**Repository Methods:**

```
public async Task<Student> FetchStudentByIdAsync(int id)
{
   return _context.Student.Where(x=>x.Id==id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

public async Task<DetailsLookup> FetchDetailByIdAsync(int id)
{
   return _context.DetailsLookup.Where(x=>x.Id==id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

**Service Method:**

```
public async Task<StudentViewModel> GetStudentViewModelAsync(int id)
{
   var model = new StudentViewModel();

   try
   {
       var student = await _repository.FetchStudentByIdAsync(id);
       if(student != null) 
       {
           var detail = await _repository.FetchDetailByIdAsync(student.GenderId);

           model.Id = student.Id,
           model.Name = student.Name,
           model.GenderId = student.GenderId
           model.GenderName = detail?.Name
       }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
   }

   return model;
}
```

As you read in that article, if you don't return custom viewmodel, how can you perform joins on tables and return data from multiple tables?

A better way would be to join tables and return a custom viewmodel directly from repo using a single call to database. This is better performance when you need a list of students with details.

```
public async Task<StudentViewModel> FetchStudentViewModelAsync(int id)
{
    return await (from s in _context.Student
                 join d in _context.DetailsLookup on s.GenderId equals d.Id
                 where s.Id == id
                 select new StudentViewModel
                 {
                     Id = s.Id,
                     Name = s.Name,
                     GenderId = s.GenderId
                     GenderName = d.Name
                 }).FirstOrDefaultAsync()
}
```

Comment: Thanks , So the best scenario if I want return list of students , using function to to get data as viewmodel and suing join query, right ?

Comment: @pesito yes, you can do both ways. In my experience, returning a viewmodel from repo using join query is more efficient because it will only make one request to database and fetch only needed fields. Whereas if you fetch both records separately and merge them in service, there will two calls to database and all fields will be fetched. Returning domain from repo makes sense when it is generic, but for your case, you need to join two tables in SQL, so you cannot do it by returning two domain objects. It has be saved into the viewmodel first and should be returned from repo.